# cannot use Edge NGram in solr 7.5

Tags: solr

I am using `solr 7.5` and I tried to use Edge NGram, but getting below error.

```
collection: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core collection: 
Can't load schema /Users/srinivaskallepalli/aem/integration-test/target/solr-7.5.0/server/solr/wnt-test_master_Products_de/conf/schema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_general_EDGE_NGRAM": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory'
```

Please check your logs for more information

Below is the schema for edge NGram

```
<fieldType name="text_general_EDGE_NGRAM" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>

            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>

            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>

        <fieldType name="text_general_EDGE_END_NGRAM" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30" side="back"/>
                <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>

            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>

            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Can somebody please help on this?

Comment: Since it tells you to check the logs, what does the log say? (my guess: the `side` parameter has been removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the attribute `side="back"` and `side="front"`. 
Removing `side="front", side="back"` from schema file will remove the error.

Use the field type as below.

```
<fieldType name="text_general_EDGE_NGRAM" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30"/>
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" />
          <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

[Please refer the link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter)

I would suggest the query type analyzer should be like below but again it all depend on your requirement.

```
<analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit for your response. Yes it works when I remove side attribute, but in this case how should I use the reverse/back edge NGram.

Comment: You can use a `ReverseStringFilter`. Should be available through `ReverseStringFilterFactory`.